# How do I stop a top header collapsing into a hamburger menu (responsive)?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the nooby question, I'm trying my best!

I have a top menu on my Wordpress website. I am only having a few short links and they WOULD fit on a mobile screen. I don't want the menu to collapse like it does now, into a hamburger menu.

Right now the code says:

```
.mobile-menu-trigger,
.ham-menu-trigger {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    padding: 30px 0;
    padding: 3rem 0;
}

.mobile-menu-trigger {
    width: 60px;
    width: 6rem;
}

.ham-menu-trigger {
    width: 24px;
    width: 2.4rem;
    display: none;
}

.header-hamburger .ham-menu-trigger {
    display: table-cell;
}

.mobile-menu-trigger-container,
.ham-menu-trigger-container {
    cursor: pointer;    
    position: relative;
    width: 24px;
    width: 2.4rem;
}

.mobile-menu-trigger-stick,
.ham-menu-trigger-stick {
    height: 4px;
    height: 0.4rem;
    width: 24px;
    width: 2.4rem;
    background-color: currentColor;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.mobile-menu-trigger-stick:last-child,
.ham-menu-trigger-stick:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;   
}
```

and the HTML is

```
               <div class="bnt-container">

                   <?php bento_mobile_menu(); ?>

                   <?php bento_primary_menu(); ?>

               </div>
           </header>
```

I hope you can help me maintain the menu's full width, like it is on desktop!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you provide the `html` too ?

Comment: @johannchopin I updated the post, hope that helps. I've been trying to sort it for over an hour with trial-and-error but I just can't figure it out.